# How do I omit specific string(s) from regex replace?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I need to loop through web addresses and remove the domain extension UNLESS the web address matches something specific. At that point I want to ignore that match entirely. I am doing this in Google Apps Script so it may be missing some newer Javascript features.

I started with the basics which works fine.

```
source.replace(/(\.\S+\b)/gi,"")
```

Now, I want to ignore the extension if the whole string is: cars.com.

```
[abc.com, yahoo.com, amazon.com, cars.com]
becomes
[abc, yahoo, amazon, cars.com]
```

I have very little experience w/ lookahead/behinds which is where my problem lies. The following attempt still removes the extension from "cars.com".

```
source.replace(/(?<!cars\S+)(\.\S+\b)/gi,"")
```

I'm pretty sure I understand why, I'm just not sure how to fix it.

Comment: What's the format of output you're looking for? JSON, Array, CSV??

Answer (score 2):

You may use a regex with negative lookahead and a capture group:

```
/\b(?!cars\.com\b)([\w-]+)\.[\w-]+/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XNVpb5/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Match word boundary
- `(?!cars\.com\b)`: Negative lookahead to discard the match of we have `cars.com` ahead of us
- `([\w-]+)\.[\w-]+`: Match a string in `foo.bar` format and capture part before dot in capture group #1
- `'\1'` is used in **replacement** to put first part back in substituted string.

**Code:**

```js
const arr = ['abc.com',
  'yahoo.com',
  'amazon.com',
  'cars.com'];
  
const re = /\b(?!cars\.com\b)([\w-]+)\.[\w-]+/;

arr.forEach(el => {
  console.log( el, '=>', el.replace(re, '\1') );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex can get really long if you have lots of urls to ignore, you can have an array of urls to ignore, map the urls array and only apply the regex if the url is not to be ignored :

```js
const urls = ["abc.com", "yahoo.com", "amazon.com", "cars.com"];
const ignore = ["cars.com", "other.com"];

const result = urls.map(url => {
  return ignore.includes(url) ? url : url.replace(/(\.\S+\b)/gi, "");
});

console.log(result);
```